# What is the word for to describe the personality type of a person who tries to show their body by not covering it?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Some people tend to show a big part of their body in their social profile. Like many seminaked, beachside, underdressed photos. I am looking for some way to refer to such personality (nouns and adjectives) in the following categories:

- approval
- neutral
- disapproval
- slang
- formal

Comment: Try + to + infinitive means that there is a difficulty and someone is making an effort to achieve/overcome/do it. Plus, you can't be **more** semi-naked; you are semi-naked or not. I think the word you need is 'seminude' which means 'partially nude'.

Comment: @orhantorunt thanks, I'm looking for a work to describe the character and not the state.

Comment: There are a lot of cultural problems with this question. best if it were closed.

Comment: The word for the personality type of a woman who appears semi-nude for fun or profit is, in Western cultures 'normal', in others, e.g. Afghanistan, etc, 'bad'. What do you want us to say?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don’t necessarily get that sense. Some people are certainly willing to bare more than others.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Your comment assumes that it is not possible to have a word for something because it is "normal."  Your comment also assumes that it *is* normal in the situations the OP asks about. Neither of these is relevant, nor in evidence. You should withdraw your comment.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem stemming in the culture in the question as the OP hasn't provided a context. Speculating on Harvey's hypothesis, I think the answers would be dangerous, not the question itself (this is why I downvoted the question doubtfuly) as it was asked to provide 'disapproval' of sharing semi-nude photos as this could be perfectly normal for many people and an exemplery sentence with 'disapproval' might be rude to some which I think we all don't want it to happen.

Comment: For disapproval, I would say "immodest".

Comment: I read the question as requiring words that three different observers (approving, neutral, disapproving) might use to describe the same type of person... with formal and  slang words for each category. For example, for slang words, approving might be 'hot' and disapproving might be 'slut'.

Comment: It all depends on whether you think it's ok or not. A big part of their body is LOL. As opposed to a small part of their body? :)

Comment: There are far too many variables here. Not even all native Anglophones have the same standards as regards the "modest -> exhibitionist" cline. And many people trying to learn English come from significantly different cultural backgrounds. Even the ***attitudes*** are a matter of opinion - certainly the ***words*** used to convey those attitudes are too variable to cover in a single question like this. And what does it say about the OP  here, that he's specifically restricting his context to ***her body*** - modest / exhibitionist ***women**?* What about the men??!!

Answer (score 4):

The word you are looking for is [exhibitionist](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/exhibitionist): a person who behaves in ways intended to attract attention or display their powers, personality, etc.

Exhibitionism is not necessarily good nor bad. It depends on context and manner. A person who compulsively exhibits themself may do it in ways that are not appropriate or that are self sabotaging. However, it is more-or-less a requirement to have some degree of exhibitionism in professions involving public performance. A stage actor who was not exhibitionist to some degree would be hampered in their career.

Comment: English is full of homographs -- as is just about every language with a writing system. Whether "exhibitionist" is a homograph for some other word is irrelevant to whether "exhibitionist" is a good answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138868/discussion-on-answer-by-billonne-what-is-the-word-for-to-describe-the-personalit).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure that there is a single word. Such people might be described as “comfortable in their own bodies” or [“comfortable in their own skin”](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/comfortable+in+my+own+skin) (perhaps in a more literal sense than the way in which that phrase is usually used). You could also say that they have a [“body-positive”](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/body-positivity-vs-body-neutrality/amp/) attitude.

Comment: There is a nuance with 'body positive' to people who lived through the 1980s.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I did live at that time but am unaware of the nuance. Please feel free to edit!

Comment: Body Positive _[a charity]_ began in 1987, with its primary goal to provide information and services for people who were newly diagnosed with HIV and asymptomatic.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh, I never connected that with “body positive”. I’ve always heard the latter term used without any negative connotation, as it is in the linked article.

Comment: There is nothing 'negative' about being sick. Stigma is a nasty thing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Of course we shouldn’t stigmatize those with HIV, but certainly nobody wants a fatal disease. It’s negative in that sense

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions you might try *shameless* which is disapproving although logically having no shame is not necessarily negative.

You specify in the title that the person is female (why?) so *slut* is quite common, at least in BrE and is very definitely disapproving. Moving further along that scale any word for a female sex worker would also be commonly used: *tart* or *whore* and many, many others.

Comment: None of those words are about clothing. They're judgments people might have about people who show a lot of skin, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: The question was about personality which I think my suggestions are, indirectly.

Answer (score -1):

approval: sexy, enticing, attractive, eye-catching
neutral: barely clothed or covered
disapproval: immodest, showing too much skin
slang: hot
formal: quasi-naked

Please feel feel edit and add adjectives to this list.